# problem when creating a class with a template

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "String.hpp"

namespace java {
      namespace lang {


template<typename  T>
class Comparable<T>  {

protected:
     virtual int8_t compareTo(T& o);
};

}


}



#endif // COMPARABLE_H
```

I haven't declared this class anywhere before

```
Comparable.h:11:7: error: explicit specialization of undeclared template class 'Comparable'
```

Comment: Please include a proper [mcve] in your question, as well as a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the build output.

Answer (score 2):

When defining a template class you don't need the template argument in the class name:

```
template<typename  T>
class Comparable<T>  { /* ... */ };
//              ^^^
//     Invalid here
```

Just remove that part:

```
template<typename  T>
class Comparable  { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: Now i have LINK error. when i extended this class

Comment: @Amos Possibly because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). Or possibly because non-abstract virtual functions *must* have a definition (implementation).

Comment: i implement this virtual function, but because of the template it is not build, probably

Comment: @Amos Then please follow the link in my comment to see the most likely problem and how to solve it.

Comment: I managed to build  with  template, using a dummy implementation of a virtual function